# How do you set the cache to expire after modification?

Tags: .htaccess, browser-cache, cache-control, last-modified, mod-expires

I'm using an .htaccess file to set the headers of a website. I want to know how to set the files cache to expire when after a modification has been made on them. Is this possible?

i.e. Will this work?

```
ExpiresDefault "modification"
```

In other words, I want the cache to stay until the files have been modified from the server.

Answer (score 2):

Expires modification sets the cache to expire a certain time after the last modification of the file.  Even if your file is modified again within the set cache time-limit, clients that have already cached the file will not look to find the new version. 
[Apache Expiration](http://books.google.ca/books?id=1z6QfgsnpKsC&lpg=PT105&ots=4uMqnvjf16&dq=apache%20what%20is%20the%20purpose%20of%20ExpiresDefault&pg=PT104#v=onepage&q=apache%20what%20is%20the%20purpose%20of%20ExpiresDefault&f=false) contains information on the expire module.

Here's an example:

```
#BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
   <filesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
      ExpiresDefault "modification plus 4 weeks"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

If your css file was modified 1 week ago, the cache will expire in 3 weeks instead of 4.

**So how do you get your newly modified css file to show up after the file has already been cached?**

If you modify your css file, the changes will *not* show up in a cached browser until the cache has expired.  One way around this issue is to change the name of the cached css file.  ( Example rename main1.css -> main2.css )

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong idea about the expires header. The expires header tells the receiver how long it can cache the file locally. After this period the receiver has to re-request the resource. If the server says a resource will expire after one hour, but the resource changes a minute later. It will take another 59 minutes until the receiver will fetch this modified version. There is no way for the the server to notify the receiver that the resource has expired prematurely.

Comment: Expires Modification is essentially the opposite of what is needed. What is needed it to set an 'expired' header to see when the cached file was last modified